# Getting data from sql to checkboxlist and writing back selected boxes to sql

Tags: c#, sql, checkboxlist

I'm new to c# and working on a registration page.
I have sql where i get games from table to checkboxlist, that works great, but  then i wont to write the selected checkboxes back to sql table with value 1 for each selected checkbox

I have tried with this code

```
        for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                str += " " + CheckBoxList1.Items[i].ToString();
            }
        }
```

But with this i get the name of the checkboxes as 1 string

Please help

This is the table today

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPVoX.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbbEN.png)

If texas NL 1000/1000 is selected i want that game has the value 1 in selected column
It is only the games with active = 1  that is shown on the checkboxlist

Before i hade static values in checkboxlist and a insert into sql
But now when i get the games from database to page if they have active = 1 i dont now how my insert into i going to bee like
This is the old insert

```
string Sqlquery1 = "insert into [CashGame].[dbo].[tblStoGame] (Förnamn,EfterNamn,Datum,texas10_10,texas25_25,texas50_50,omaha10_10,omaha25_25,omaha50_50,Nickname,IDcard,MemberID) values ('" + Forename.Text + "','" + Lastname.Text + "',now(),'" + CheckBoxList1.Items[0].Selected + "','" + CheckBoxList1.Items[1].Selected + "','" + CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem.Value + "','" + Texas50_50 + "','" + Omaha10_10 + "','" + Omaha25_25 + "','" + Omaha50_50 + "','" + Nickname.Text + "','" + IDCard.Text + "','" + MemberID.Text + "')";
```

Comment: Entity Framework or ADO?

Comment: Dollar says its ADO. Without parameters!:)

Comment: What does "write it back to table with 1" mean? What does your table look like now? What should it look like after you're done?

Comment: @BryanDellinger so, about that dollar... 

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly your questions is. I believe the trouble is you get the name of the checkboxes as one string?

If what you want is a list of strings for the selected items, you could do:

```
List<string> selectedItems = CheckBoxList1.Items
    .Where(item => item.Selected)
    .Select(item => item.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

Here LINQ is used to first get a list of selected items (`Where`), and then select from that list extract the names (`ToString`), and finally return the result as a list of strings (`ToList`).

You now have a list of strings with names of selected intems, instead of a single long string.

If your questions was regarding SQL and the table, you should provide some more examples of the technology/methods you are using to read/write from database.

Comment: OP is not a programmer... Just wants a quick hacky solution to a problem... That is why we  don't get shown the code that really matters... Don't bother...

Comment: Dusan, please tell me what you need

Comment: Frode
i have updated with information and insert into

Comment: Anyone who can help?